# JQuery show or hide effect

Tags: jquery, html

I tried to do a slide open effect but I couldn't. At last I found this but I couldn't integrate to my page. Please help.

This works the way I want: http://jsfiddle.net/Hftpc/17/

This is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/LGU8E/

edit: You said I don't understand what do you want?
I will explain detailed:
Did you see this? : http://jsfiddle.net/Hftpc/17/
I want to do this for my page: http://jsfiddle.net/LGU8E/
while My mouse is on quickstartdiv, this effect (I give it:http://jsfiddle.net/LGU8E/) runs and visiblepanel div opens like this=http://jsfiddle.net/LGU8E/ but not vertical, it is horizontal..
I hope I can explain it..

Comment: Can you update your question to explain what effect you are trying to achieve, with specifics about where it is failing? You can even include relevant snippets of code to make it easier for answers to see the problem.

Comment: You can't include ASP tags inside html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle requires some work to make it pure HTML and appropriate javascript. First, you need to use jQuery and jQuery UI (for the animations) instead of MooTools.  Second, you can't use ASP tags in the fiddle, you need to convert that to HTML.  You don't need the document ready handler, as jsFiddle allows you to specify that in the options (onDomReady is what I chose).  I also had some problems with your CSS since it isn't designed to work in the fiddle environment -- your absolute positioning moves things outside the display area.  After a bit of tweaking, I came up with [this fiddle,](http://jsfiddle.net/eUjpX/) which seems to work the way you want it.  You'll just have to adjust the CSS (and HTML) to fit.

Comment: I don't understand. What is wrong in my CSS? I wanted to do this CSS but you changed. Do I have to use it? Okey I understand that, I cannot use asp.net items in this content..

Comment: @dmrc1143 - nothing was visible until I remove the left positioning and margin-left settings.  In your real app, these would probably be ok, but in the fiddle it made it invisible.

Comment: sir, maybe you are right but It didn't work probably in my real app. I saw, It was like this ==>http://jsfiddle.net/LGU8E/2/

Comment: @dmrc1143 - you could probably put the CSS back the way it was.  In retrospect, I guess all the change really did was get rid of the (nearly invisible to me) horizontal scroll bar in the display frame.

Comment: I can't understand you sorry..
But the property margin-left:50% of CSS is breaking my 'hideandshow' div..
But I need this (margin-left:50%) CSS property. What can I do?

Comment: @dmrc1143 - you might want to play with putting both elements in a wrapper container and position that container absolutely where you need it.  Leave the interior DIVs to display relatively inside the absolute DIV.  I thought it was working in the last link, though.

Answer (score 1):

It requires jQuery and jQuery UI to run those animations,

[Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/LGU8E/2/)

**[Edit]** I still have no idea what you are trying to do, if you want it to open vertically, change that "horizontal" keyword to "vertical". If you want to do something else, tell us what that is.

Comment: I think you mean 'It' requires jQuery and jQuery UI.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, I wanna do this, but this Css that you set is not mine. I wrote my CSS but It didn`t work, I couldn't see openin' animaiton when I changed it..